# find data from another sheet dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I don't really know how to precisely lookup for that so please tell me if I'm doing something wrong there.
But I'd like to dynamically call a sheet using a value in the cell.
Actually it doesn't work since it displays only the text as you may see. I tried to add `=SUM()` but it calculate 0.
the formula is `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(CELL("contents";A1)&"!B2"))`

Here is a [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wzZSzoixxsJMMqMItZYNt0W5aWMFwohl3FKaeXB6dJc/edit?usp=sharing) for testing

Thanks for the sweet help.

[image]

Comment: What is `contents`? And what do you mean by *"collect"*. What doesn't work? I believe you need to share a test sheet.

Comment: added the sheet :)

Comment: It is locked. You need to make it public.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Edited.

Comment: Not very helpful I'm afraid. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean it's not working ? I'm able to edit the sheet in a private tab actually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) function

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(B2&"!D2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Yep, sorry took some time, was dinner time :)
have a nice day or night!